# Django URL cannot be found

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django and use this tutorial for learning https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/
Have a little problem with routing in.

View code:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(r'<h3 style="font-style: bold;">Index</h3>')
```

URL config code:

**1. blog/urls**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

**2.project/urls**

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

When i come for 127.0.0.1:8080/index that

**Page not found** (404)

Using the URLconf defined in les1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. ^blog/
2. ^admin/

The current URL, index, didn't match any of these.

**Struct of project**

```
blog/
    templates
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
les1/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

Can't find error:(

Comment: Please update your question with the url that you are you trying to access, and the full error message that you are getting.

Comment: Sounds like an http server as apache is looking for an index.html. How do you run the http server for your django project?

Comment: remove the r from the view response.

Comment: Has **blog** been definitely been added to your apps in `settings.py` - it is possible you could give a high level overview of your directory structure as well please?

Comment: @ham-sandwich added in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the actual url you enter in your browser ? is it `127.0.0.1:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000/index` ? From your post, I assume it is the second:

```
The current URL, index, didn't match any of these.
```

What if you enter `127.0.0.1:8000/blog` ?

`index` is the name of your route, used only on server-side. It's a shortcut used for quick reversing and displaying of URL:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

print(reverse('index'))
# will output "/blog", which is the actual URL
```

Comment: Well, is it not just a prefix?
When i set '^blog/$' prefix it is not workig too.

Comment: It is not a prefix, it is your route identifier for url reversing, on server-side (django). You cannot use it from client-side (web browser).

Answer (score -1):

Remove r from view code.

`def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h3 style="font-style: bold;">Index</h3>')`

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it has not solved my problem

Comment: I know that @ColonelThirtyTwo but that error was not defined before.

Comment: Why has been this answer downvoted? It certainly doesn't solve the questioned problem, nevertheless it pinpoints another error, that should be obviously fixed.